# Add new row with sum when value changes in column DataTable / DataGridview

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, datagridview

I'm trying to add a new row with the sum of the columns when the value of the first column "Unidad" changes. Here's a picture showing the two rows i would like to add the new row in between of.
[![where i want to inser the new row][1]][1]
I'm using datatable to fetch the data from an azure sql Table and inserting it in a Datagridview. Working with C# and WPF
EDIT:

```
    private void llenarTabla()
    {
        int mes = Convert.ToInt32(meses.SelectedIndex + 1);
        int year = Convert.ToInt32(ano.Text);

        string recaudacion = numAdmin.Text;

        string mostrarTurnos = "SELECT * FROM TablaSalidas WHERE noAdmin=" + recaudacion + "AND MONTH (fecha)=" + mes + "AND YEAR(fecha)=" + year + "ORDER BY (noUnidad) ASC, fecha";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(mostrarTurnos, sc);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        tabla.DataSource = dt;


        tabla.Columns["noUnidad"].HeaderText = "Unidad";
        tabla.Columns["fecha"].HeaderText = "Fecha";
        tabla.Columns["noRuta"].HeaderText = "No. Ruta";
        tabla.Columns["noTerminal"].HeaderText = "No. Terminal";
        tabla.Columns["noRecaudador"].HeaderText = "No. Recaudador";
        tabla.Columns["noAdmin"].HeaderText = "No. de Admin";
        tabla.Columns["nomAdmin"].HeaderText = "Nombre de Admin";
        tabla.Columns["importeSalida"].HeaderText = "Imp. entregado";
        tabla.Columns["importeRuta"].HeaderText = "Imp. de ruta";
        tabla.Columns["importeDevengado"].HeaderText = "Imp. devengado";
        tabla.Columns["nombreRuta"].HeaderText = "Ruta";
        tabla.Columns["nomAdmin"].Visible = false;
        tabla.Columns["noTerminal"].Visible = false;
        tabla.Columns["noRecaudador"].Visible = false;
        tabla.Columns["noAdmin"].Visible = false;

        tabla.Columns["importeSalida"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
        tabla.Columns["importeRuta"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
        tabla.Columns["importeDevengado"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";


        tabla.Columns["Estado"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        tabla.Columns["noUnidad"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        tabla.Columns["noRuta"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        tabla.Columns["fecha"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        tabla.Columns["nombreRuta"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        tabla.Columns["importeRuta"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        tabla.Columns["Estado"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;


        tabla.Columns["noUnidad"].DisplayIndex = 0;
        tabla.Columns["fecha"].DisplayIndex = 1;
        tabla.Columns["nombreRuta"].DisplayIndex = 2;
        tabla.Columns["nombreRuta"].DisplayIndex = 3;
        tabla.Columns["Estado"].DisplayIndex = 4;
        tabla.Columns["importeSalida"].DisplayIndex = 5;
        tabla.Columns["importeRuta"].DisplayIndex = 6;
        tabla.Columns["importeRuta"].DisplayIndex = 7;
        tabla.Columns["importeDevengado"].DisplayIndex = 8;

        tabla.Columns["Estado"].Visible = false;



        tabla.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        tabla.AllowUserToAddRows = false;


        //Crea una linea nueva y agrega el total de la suma de importe de ruta
        decimal total1 = 0;
        string sacarTotal1 = "SELECT SUM (importeRuta) FROM TablaSalidas WHERE MONTH (fecha)=" + mes + "AND YEAR (fecha)=" + year + "AND noAdmin=" + numAdmin.Text;
        SqlCommand cmdTotal1 = new SqlCommand(sacarTotal1, sc);
        sc.Open();
        SqlDataReader drTotal1 = cmdTotal1.ExecuteReader();
        if (drTotal1.Read())
        {
            total1 = Convert.ToDecimal(drTotal1.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
        sc.Close();
        //Agrega la columna con la suma
        DataRow rowImporte1 = dt.NewRow();
        rowImporte1["importeRuta"] = total1.ToString();
        rowImporte1["nombreRuta"] = "Total";
        dt.Rows.Add(rowImporte1);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        tabla.DataSource = dt;


        //Crea una linea nueva y agrega el total de la suma de importe de salida
        decimal total = 0;
        string sacarTotal = "SELECT SUM (importeSalida) FROM TablaSalidas WHERE MONTH (fecha)=" + mes + "AND YEAR (fecha)=" + year + "AND noAdmin=" + numAdmin.Text;
        SqlCommand cmdTotal = new SqlCommand(sacarTotal, sc);
        sc.Open();
        SqlDataReader drTotal = cmdTotal.ExecuteReader();
        if (drTotal.Read())
        {
            total = Convert.ToDecimal(drTotal.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
        sc.Close();
        //Agrega la columna con la suma
        rowImporte1["importeSalida"] = total.ToString();

        dt.AcceptChanges();
        tabla.DataSource = dt;

        //Crea una linea nueva y agrega el total de la suma de importe de salida
        decimal total2 = 0;
        string sacarTotal2 = "SELECT SUM (importeDevengado) FROM TablaSalidas WHERE MONTH (fecha)=" + mes + "AND YEAR (fecha)=" + year + "AND noAdmin=" + numAdmin.Text;
        SqlCommand cmdTotal2 = new SqlCommand(sacarTotal2, sc);
        sc.Open();
        SqlDataReader drTotal2 = cmdTotal2.ExecuteReader();
        if (drTotal2.Read())
        {
            total2 = Convert.ToDecimal(drTotal2.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
        sc.Close();
        //Agrega la columna con la suma
        rowImporte1["importeDevengado"] = total2.ToString();

        dt.AcceptChanges();
        tabla.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

This is the code i use to fill the datagridview with the sql command, the insert works correctly, the only thing i'd like to add is a row in between changin values in the first column.
Ex. When "Unidad" changes from 136 to 256 add a column below the last 136 and above the first 256 the sums the values of all columns
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLfWM.png

Comment: Can you show what code you have so far?  Also highlight what you're trying to do on the insert and where it fails.  This should be a simple fix once we see the code.